# Convert String to BigInteger without Losing Leading Zeroes

Tags: java

**Input**:

```java
new BigInteger( "0010637234689" );
```

**Output**:

```
10637234689
```

I am using a [Soap Web Service](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/Void_Air_Ticket) that requires a BigInteger as the ticket number in the request, but it doesn't match it when I don't include the leading zeroes.

Example: If I send an XML from postman with the leading zeroes, I get a success.

```xml
<VoidTicketRQ Version="2.1.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Ticketing eTicketNumber="0010637234689"/>
</VoidTicketRQ>
```

Unfortunately the stubs that are auto-generated by the wsdl files available from that service use a BigInteger, so I cannot populate the payload using a String.

```java
public static class Ticketing
{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "eTicketNumber")
    protected BigInteger eTicketNumber;
}
```

How can I retain the leading zeroes in a BigInteger?

Comment: "it doesn't match it when I don't include the leading zeroes" - wait, so are you saying it *did* match when you included leading zeroes, i.e. you already successfully sent BigIntegers that include leading zeroes to the service? Some more details/code about that would be helpful. BigIntegers and leading zeroes are mutually exclusive, so it's a contradiction for a service to require both - either a plain BigInteger is expected and something else is going wrong, or the service accepts a String or some other type with leading zeroes.

Comment: Given that BigIntegers and leading zeroes are mutually exclusive, it seems like it may be a bug on their side, or a bug with how the stubs are generated (or it's a problem unrelated to this). I would suggest trying a different request which doesn't require this field to see if that works, checking the full exact response you get back to see if that points to a different problem and looking at the raw WSDL files to see whether that field is a type that should allow leading zeroes and reaching out to the customer support of the web service if the WSDL files are wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up modifying the xsd file to set eTicketNumber as a string and regenerated the stubs. `<xs:attribute name="eTicketNumber" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>`. I will report the issue like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You will need to store your "integer" as a `String` object and convert it as you need to perform you `BigInteger` operations.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of digits required are always 13 (quite unlucky), you can send a formatted String:

```
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger("0010637234689"); // Or "10637234689"
    System.out.printf("%d = %013d%n", n, n);
```

Will give:

```
10637234689 = 0010637234689
```

So use `String.format("%013d", n)`.